# c# winforms evenly distribute 3 controls

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 3 custom controls, that i want to place in a resizable window next to each other. when the window is being resized, these controls should also resize, each taking 33% of the available width.

i tried to use a table layout, but it seems the table only grows, but never shrinks.

thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Please describe what you mean by 'never shrinks'. That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: i mean, that when i make the window bigger, the tablelayout grows with it. but when i make the window smaller, the tablelayout stays as it is.

Comment: @matt: that is not the normal behavior. Try it on a clean Form. Ksempac's answer is correct.

Comment: yeah, when i put it on a clean form it works. but i just cant find the difference between the clean form and mine...

Comment: @matt: finding those difference is another matter. You should probably inspect the *.Designer.cs sources.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a TableLayoutPanel, with 3 columns each of size "33% percent". Then you put each of your control in the panel, and set the anchor property as you wish (for example right-left if your control should resize themselves only on the horizontal plane).

Your TableLayoutPanel should also have its property Dock set to True so that he can occupy all your window and resize accordingly.

Comment: thanks but that is exactly what i did already, but as i said the tablelayout only grows, but never shrinks

Comment: There are several things you need to check : Did you set the Dock property of your control ? If you didn't, what are the values of its Anchor property ? Does the layout resize itself in all directions ? Are you sure the layout isn't resizing ? If the layout tries to resize, but your control don't (because they haven't no anchor or dock property set) you won't see it.

Comment: Sorry in the first question i meant "Did you set the Dock property of your TableLayoutPanel ?".

Comment: the anchor of the tablelayout is set to top,left,right,bottom. i.e. it resizes in all directions. i dont want to set the dock property since it would overlap other controls. so yes, the tablelayout resizes in all directions but does not shrink anymore. inside the tables of the tablelayout i have set the control's dock to fill.

Comment: Did you check that your layout's columns are set to a size in percent and not a fixed size ? Sorry if the question seems stupid, but I try to go through all possible problems. I know tablelayoutpanel works, since I'm currently creating Outlook 2007 forms with this kind of layout everywhere.

Comment: yes, they are in percent. and actually the enlarging works pretty well. all three components scale at 1/3 of the total available width. it's just the shrinking that does not work. the components just stay at their current size and look cropped.

Comment: Do your controls/layout have a minimum size set ? What kind of controls do you use in your layout (i know they are custom, but i suppose they inherit/looks like one or more standard controls) ?

Comment: try setting AutoSizeMode property to GrowAndShrink

Comment: their minimum and their maximum size is set to 0,0.
the custom control is a colleciton of sliders, buttons, textboxes.

and i was a wrong on the fact that they are directly inside the tablecell. actually there is a groupbox between them. 
so it is:
table->tablecell->groupbox->customcontrol

sorry about that!

GrowAndShrink didnt help

Comment: I just want to thank you for this answer, I have been working on this for a few days now, and this helped me so much!